# How to efficiently calculate pairwise *differences* between values in a list (tensor) in pythorch?

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, pairwise

Given an 1D tensor:

```
tensor([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6.])
```

the expected result is:

```
tensor([-1., -2., -3., -4., -5., -1., -2., -3., -4., -1., -2., -3., -1., -2., -1.])
```

The 'nearest' solution using the tensor library is to calculate the 1-norm distance. However this returns the absolute values, not the differences:

```
import torch
x = torch.tensor([[1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6.]])
torch.pdist(x, p=1)
# tensor([1., 2., 3., 4., 5., 1., 2., 3., 4., 1., 2., 3., 1., 2., 1.])
```

Other approach is to broadcast. However, this results in a square matrix, including meaningless lower triangular values:

```
x = torch.tensor([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6.])
x[:, None] - x[None, :]
# tensor([[ 0., -1., -2., -3., -4., -5.],
#        [ 1.,  0., -1., -2., -3., -4.],
#        [ 2.,  1.,  0., -1., -2., -3.],
#        [ 3.,  2.,  1.,  0., -1., -2.],
#        [ 4.,  3.,  2.,  1.,  0., -1.],
#        [ 5.,  4.,  3.,  2.,  1.,  0.]])
```

In this case, a function like scipy's squareform would help, but I am not sure whether it will broke the differentiability of the loss function which includes this step.

Even another approach is to employ a python loop, subtracting one element at a time from a slice starting from the next element until the last one. Finally, concatenating all results in a single tensor.
However, I suppose this is not worth trying because of slowness and will probably mess  with gradient calculations.

Answer (score 0):

Up to this moment, the best I could do, using masking:

```
x = torch.tensor([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6.])
dis = x.view(-1,1)-x.view(1,-1)
mask = torch.triu(torch.ones(dis.shape), diagonal=1).bool()
dis[mask]
# tensor([-1., -2., -3., -4., -5., -1., -2., -3., -4., -1., -2., -3., -1., -2., -1.])
```

Unfortunately, this is 10x slower than the pdist approach. On the other hand, it gives the expected result.

EDIT

This is 8x slower than pdist, using indexing:

```
 x = torch.tensor([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6.])
 dis = x.view(-1,1)-x.view(1,-1)
 indices = torch.triu_indices(*dis.shape, offset=1)
 dis[indices[0], indices[1]]
 # tensor([-1., -2., -3., -4., -5., -1., -2., -3., -4., -1., -2., -3., -1., -2., -1.])
```

EDIT

For the sake of completeness, this is 24x slower than pdist, using python loop:

```
 x = torch.tensor([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6.])
 l = [x[i]-x[i+1:] for i in range(x.shape[0])]
 torch.concat(l)
 # tensor([-1., -2., -3., -4., -5., -1., -2., -3., -4., -1., -2., -3., -1., -2., -1.])
```

EDIT

This is 7x slower than pdist, using x.unsqueeze:

```
 x = torch.tensor([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6.])
 dis = x.unsqueeze(1) - x
 indices = torch.triu_indices(*dis.shape, offset=1)
 dis[indices[0], indices[1]]
 # tensor([-1., -2., -3., -4., -5., -1., -2., -3., -4., -1., -2., -3., -1., -2., -1.])
```

Comment: This is frustrating because, in theory, we know pdist performs more calculation than the mere differences.

Comment: What vector size you use for performance testing?